# Python & Pandas: How to return a copy of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the problem. I use a function to return a randomized data,

```
data1 = [3,5,7,3,2,6,1,6,7,8]
data2 = [1,5,2,1,6,4,3,2,7,8]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['c1'])
df['c2'] = data2

def randomize_data(df):
    df['c1_ran'] = df['c1'].apply(lambda x: (x + np.random.uniform(0,1)))
    df['c1']=df['c1_ran']
    # df.drop(['c1_ran'], 1, inplace=True)
    return df

temp_df = randomize_data(df)

display(df)
display(temp_df)
```

However, the `df` (source data) and the `temp_df` (randomized_data) is the same. Here is the result:

[image]

How can I make the `temp_df` and `df` different from each other?

---

I find I can get rid of the problem by adding `df.copy()` at the beginning of the function

```
def randomize_data(df):
    df = df.copy()
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right way to deal with it?

Comment: Yes. It is. So... probably should just delete this question because `df.copy()` is the answer, which you're already doing :P

Comment: @WayneWerner is it possible to make `.copy()` a default option in custom functions? I feel its very redundent when you want to return the `df`. And this need you to add `df=df.copy()` a lot of times in the function.

Comment: @WayneWerner Or, am I using it wrong? Is there better way to return a df in a custom function?

Comment: You should either a) call your function like `do_something(df.copy())` or b) call `df = df.copy()` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: what is difference between df and temp_df?

Answer (score 2):

Use `DataFrame.assign()`:

```
def randomize_data(df):
    return df.assign(c1=df.c1 + np.random.uniform(0, 1, df.shape[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right, and DataFrame.copy() have an optional argument 'deep'. You can find details in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html