# Python & Pandas: Will using many df.copy affect code's performance?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing some data analysis, and the data are in pandas `DataFrame`, `df`.

There are several function that I defined to do process on the `df`.

For encapsulation purpose, I define the functions like this:

```
def df_process(df):
    df=df.copy()
    # do some process work on df
    return df
```

In Jupyter Notebook, I use the function as

```
df = df_process(df)
```

The reason for using `df.copy()` is that otherwise the original `df` would be modified, whether you assign it back or not. (see [Python & Pandas: How to return a copy of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579921/python-pandas-how-to-return-a-copy-of-a-dataframe))

My question is:

1. Is using `df=df.copy()` proper here? If not, how should a function handle data be defined?
2. Since I use several such data processing function, will it affect my program's performance? And how much?

Comment: Using more memory will often make run times longer. How much longer? Measure it.

Comment: Why would the original df be modified *whether you assign it back or not*? In the linked question you are adding a new column to the original df, and HYRY's answer shows you how to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far better would be:

```
def df_process(df):
    # do some process work on df

def df_another(df):
    # other processing

def df_more(df):
    # yet more processing

def process_many(df):
    for frame_function in (df_process, df_another, df_more):
        df_copy = df.copy()
        frame_function(df_copy)
        # emit the results to a file or screen or whatever
```

The key here is if you must make a copy, make only one, process it, stash the results somewhere and then dispose of it by reassigning `df_copy`. Your question made no mention of why you are hanging onto processed copies so this assumes you need not.